# Include pdf repeatedly

Tags: xetex, pdfpages, loops

I use `includepdf`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{pdfpages} 
\begin{document} 
\includepdf[pages=1,booklet,turn=false,landscape]{singlepagedoc.pdf} 
\end{document}
```

How can I include it number of count (16, 32 etc.)?

Not to write

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{pdfpages} 
\begin{document} 
\includepdf[pages=1,booklet,turn=false,landscape]{singlepagedoc.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=1,booklet,turn=false,landscape]{singlepagedoc.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=1,booklet,turn=false,landscape]{singlepagedoc.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=1,booklet,turn=false,landscape]{singlepagedoc.pdf}
#.....
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages), you can use:

> **duplicatepages** Duplicates each page  times, with  being the argument to this option. (Default: duplicatepages=2)